# field or property \“CreatablesInfo\” does not exist

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio, web-services, sharepoint-server

I´m developing a Sharepoint 2013 on premise webservice and I consult many lists but in one list I have a error: **field or property \“CreatablesInfo\” does not exist**. 
Error is in `context.ExecuteQuery()` according visual studio 2013

```
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = "<View>" +
                                "<Query>" +
                                    "<Where>" +
                                        "<And>" +
                                            "<IsNull>" +
                                                "<FieldRef Name='ID_x0020_Aplicacion' />" +
                                            "</IsNull>" +
                                            "<Gt>" +
                                                "<FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
                                                "<Value Type=DateTime>2016-11-30T12:00:00Z</Value>" +
                                            "</Gt>" +
                                        "</And>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                                "</Query>" +
                            "</View>";
            ListItemCollection itemCollection = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(itemCollection);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Note: list, context and same code work perfectly with other lists.

Comment: Sorry, I revolved this question.

Comment: Can you share how you solved this issue?

Comment: If there's no answer of any sort, please just delete the question.